# List of items with status

Tags: icons, design, mobile-application, ux-designer, app

I'm working on the design of an app with a holiday request list.
Each request has a type (Holidays, Illness, etc) a pair of dates, and an Status.
The Status can be:

- Pending:
- Approved:
- Denied:

I'm not sure about how to correctly represent the status in the list, and with which kind of icons (or is better to use texts?)

Additionally,  some request may need to be justified, and when needed, the status can be:

- Justified = Yes
- Justified = No

I really don't know where and how can I represent the need of justification on some request.

Can you help me to decide if it's better to use an icon set (ideas?) or a text to describe the status?  And tips about where and how to put the Justification Yes/No     in some of the requests?

[image: RequestFormListApp]

Comment: by Justificated I think you mean that is the holiday recognized? So if the user is Christian or Muslim they will need different holidays off. So are you asking how can a manager see if the holiday is recognized by the company and that the employee needs to have this holiday off?

Answer (score 1):

Your listing is proper but it will be better if you keep text instead of icons. Because when the user sees it, they can't understand easily the meaning of it. And if you want to keep icons only then just change the icon of "Pending" status because it seems like download. Generally we are showing clock symbol to denote pending status. And in your listing the second name is overlapping the date so it should not be there. Instead just fix the max width to see the text and text is long then break it and show in next line. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the solution to display Justification.

[image]

Comment: Really thanks for the tips!
And for the Justificated  status.... any oppinion?

Comment: @Tirma Actually I am little bit confused and I want one example like in which scenario you want to display justificated status? Because I want to just know that what I understand is right or wrong.So based on that I can help you to give proper answer.

Comment: For example, i can request a few days of holidays because i got married. My boss can Accept or Deny my request. If the request is accepted, i can enjoy the holidays, but after that, i need to give to my boos a proof of my marriage. That proof is the justification. If i dont give the proof, my holidays will be in status  NOT JUSTIFICATED, but if do, it will be justificated.

Answer (score 1):

According to some well-respected people who have done a lot of research on icons, [label your icons](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/).

I'd suggest do some simple testing on your own. Just print out your screen layouts and ask people what they think the icons mean. You'll learn a lot with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am not sure having fully understand all your needs, but I tried: I've shorten the informations displayed. Here the core information (to me) is the date from-to of the holiday requested. Others informations just give the status of my holiday request (pending, approved, denied AND the call to action). Here I used the current trending model of swipe on band to perform an action. Swiping right you can upload the justificatory (where available), while swiping left you can delete the request from the list (I am not sure if this option is needed).
Hope this helps!